# How to merge remote and local Git branches and retrieve lost files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

[image]I was working on project with local git setup. Then I set up one in Bitbucket, and I tried to merge, but I messed up, and lost a lot of files. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: If you committed the files they’re not lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have lost *committed* files, you first action should be to check the reflog.

See [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): your commit will be listed there, and you can reset your branch to it, re-starting from *before* your merge.